# How can I pass the event listeners and other properties of one js link to another by class only in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addthis

I'm using the addthis.com social media widget, and I want to customize the bubble link that opens every service. I tried css and jquery to customize the background image but that doesn't work, because the widget overrides it. Doesn't even work with !IMPORTANT inline override.

Is there a simple way to transfer all the event listeners and non-style properties to another link with jquery? Like the onclick="" functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can register an event for when someone clicks to get the full list of services. A quick example would be:

```
function shareEventHandler(evt) { 
    console.log("Menu is now open");
}

addthis.addEventListener('addthis.menu.open', shareEventHandler);
```

You can then add your own custom logic/code. Full documentation is here:

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api#events